# Can this function be written in more efficient way?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield-return

I am just getting the days of the week back from the function. If it is a holiday week then just adding word 'holiday' after each day.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetDays(bool isHolidayWeek)
    {
        var days= new List<string>() { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
        var i = 0;
        if (isHolidayWeek)
            foreach (var day in days)
                days[i++] = day + " Holiday";

        return days;
    }
```

so can this be written in a more efficient way? Perhaps using yield return?

Comment: Define "more efficient" in this context. More speed? Less memory used?

Comment: By using `yield return` it doesn't make the function more efficient. It just means that the function isn't executed until the IEnumerable is enumerated.

Comment: Your code throws an exception `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`

Comment: Here's how I would implement this particular method - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/4a61a21c4cd4aa5fca5b2bb3322e6b16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method from `System.Linq` to simplify your code and return a day names with `Holiday` added (when `isHolidayWeek` equals `true`). Moving the `Days` collection outside the method can also help to minimize a memory consumption (at little bit)

```cs
public static readonly IList<string> Days = new List<string>()
    {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"};

public static IEnumerable<string> GetDays(bool isHolidayWeek)
{
    if (isHolidayWeek)
        return Days.Select(d => $"{d} Holiday");
    return Days;
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that there is no need at all to new up an array everytime you call this method, it's an unnecessary waste of resources. What is going to change in `days` between calls?

Comment: Moving `days` outside is easy

Comment: Thanks Pavel for the anwer. Newing up such a small array is not a big deal, we are living in 2020, not in 1980s, where you have to very cautious of your memory. I will keep the array in the function as it belongs/relate to this function only. Cheers

Comment: Of course its easy, but that is the main optimization, not using linq, and it was missing in your original answer. Linq as a matter of fact is probably a deoptimization for such a simpe scenario.

Comment: Also, why projection? Now you are projecting the same thing over and over again. Why not simply create the array with the holiday literals to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.

Why new up an array everytime you are calling the function? Are the days going to change between calls? Last time I cheked, they havent in the last 500 years or so (probably more). Create a string array outside the method call that stores the days with the needed suffix literals and simply use that array whenever you need to.

Comment: In addition, string concatenation inside a loop is "evil"...  consider using days[i++]=$"{day} Holiday";

Answer (score 0):

I’m going to answer as if you’re purely talking about optimising for speed.

Have the check for the bool at the start of the function before you initialise anything. 
Replace the foreach with a for loop and the list with an array of strings (you’re always going to have seven days of the week for its size). Either of those replacements improve looping speed internally and combined they should make your loop around 5 times more efficient performance wise. This is significant if you’re using this method a large amount.